Who is this spider, and what is it carrying?
I'm in Fort Worth, and, while out on the trails yesterday, I saw a whole bunch of funnel-spider webs.  Nearby I saw a strangely textured web in the grass, and, when I leaned closer to investigate, saw something that looked a bit like a spider like a spider with some extra parts.  At first I thought that it might be two spiders (and I'm not 100% sure that it's not), but, on looking at the pictures I took, it looks more like one spider carrying something.  See the blob on the bottom right of the spider.  It doesn't obviously look to me like wrapped prey.
Assuming I'm understanding correctly that this is a spider carrying something, rather than a very large spider with an unusual body plan, I'd estimate it was about 80% the size of a wolf spider.  As an additional, very rough, guide to size, you can see some blades of grass in the background.  Although this picture was taken yesterday, it may be relevant to mention that this has been an unseasonably warm October (it was about 90 ℉).


Its the exoskeleton of a spider. The thing thats "carried" is the carapace which usually sits at top and is still attached over some skin of the abdomen.

@Lukas4235, re, cool, thanks! So this is not a living spider at all, but the result of some sort of molting, or the remains of a dead spider, or something like that? If you would like to leave this as an answer (especially if you can make out from this washed-out picture what kind of spider it is, but even if not), then I would be pleased to accept it.

yes it molts in order to grow. With that it can regenerate extremities, chelicerae. I don't know which spider, initially I would have guessed some jumping spider whre this comvex carapave and thick legs occur. but with that web thats unlikely. you can go to inaturalist website, search for spiders in the location you found that and compare.

Re, thanks!  Since this is 10 days old, I don't think that there's a rush to ID the spider, so I would be happy to accept your comments as an answer.
